# Pivot table in R with a column for each hour of the day

Tags: r, time, pivot-table

I'm trying to recreate a pivot table in R I routinely create in Excel.

The raw data looks like this except thousands of rows (de-identified):

```
ORDER_ID        ACT_DATE    ACT_TIME    ACT_TYPE                                    NURSE_UNIT  FACILITY_AREA   USER_NAME                                                    
111 2/28/2020   12:04   MODIFY                                      BG RCU      BGMC            User 1
112 2/27/2020   17:50   MODIFY                                      BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
113 2/27/2020   17:50   MODIFY                                      BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
114 2/27/2020   14:31   CANCEL/DC                                   BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
115 2/28/2020   6:03    CANCEL/DC                                   BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
116 2/28/2020   6:03    CANCEL/DC                                   BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
117 2/28/2020   10:29   CANCEL/DC                                   BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
118 2/28/2020   9:20    MODIFY                                      BG CCU E    BGMC            User 3                                                  
119 2/24/2020   12:43   VERIFY                                      BG 5 Sou    BGMC            User 4                                                 
110 2/26/2020   9:08    CANCEL/DC                                   BG 6 Sou    BGMC            User 5                                                  
111 2/27/2020   17:50   MODIFY                                      BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2                                           
112 2/28/2020   5:57    CANCEL/DC                                   BG CCU E    BGMC            User 2
```

The source code:

```
library(dplyr)

bgmcOrderAction <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\bgmc_order_action_report_20200223.csv')

# filter the data
byUnit <- bgmcOrderAction %>%
  # remove this strange extra column
  select(-c(X)) %>%

  #remove extra white space
  mutate(USER_NAME = trimws(USER_NAME)) %>%
  mutate(ACT_TYPE = trimws(ACT_TYPE)) %>%
  mutate(ACT_TIME = trimws(ACT_TIME)) %>%
  mutate(NURSE_UNIT = trimws(NURSE_UNIT)) %>%
  mutate(FACILITY_AREA = trimws(FACILITY_AREA)) %>%

  # convert the time from HH:MM to just HH
  mutate(ACT_HR = substr(ACT_TIME, 1, 2)) %>%

  # we're interested in the quantity of order actions in each nurse unit per hour
  group_by(NURSE_UNIT, ACT_HR) %>%

  #mutate(count = n()) %>%
  summarise(ACT_COUNT = n())
byUnit
```

NURSE_UNIT: the nurse unit description
ACT_HR: the hour the action occurred
ACT_COUNT: the summarized count of each unique occurrence

```
> byUnit
# A tibble: 688 x 3
# Groups:   NURSE_UNIT [36]
   NURSE_UNIT ACT_HR ACT_COUNT
   <chr>      <chr>      <int>
 1 BG 2 Sou   01            15
 2 BG 2 Sou   09             2
 3 BG 2 Sou   12            16
 4 BG 2 Sou   15            15
 5 BG 2 Sou   17            29
 6 BG 2 Sou   18            44
 7 BG 2 Sou   19            14
 8 BG 2 Sou   20            16
 9 BG 2 Sou   21            43
10 BG 2 Sou   22            30
# ... with 678 more rows
```

My desired output would look something like this (basically a heat map-type layout) where the row labels are each nurse unit only once and the column labels are each hour of the day (military time) only once. The number in the table represents ACT_COUNT for that particular nurse unit at that particular hour. The goal is to learn how many actions are occurring at each hour of the day in each nurse unit.

Example output:

```
          0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
Unit1     0  1  5  0  7  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   2   0   1   8   9   0   0   3   4   5   1
Unit2     0  0  1  0  2  1  0  0  0  0  0   6   0   0   4   0   8   0   0   0   3   0   2   0
Unit3     0  1  2  0  4  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   2   0   1   0   9   3   0   3   4   1   1
Unit4     0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   4   1   8   9   0   0   0   4   1   1
BG 2 Sou  0  15 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0   0   16  0   0   15  0   29  44  0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: It would be a little easier if you made a reproducible example, but I think you can simply use: `tapply(byUnitHour$ACT_COUNT,byUnitHour[,1:2],sum)` Let me know if that does what you need and I can formalize the answer.

Comment: This worked. I will fix the question to make this more clear. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. FWIW, if you take a header of your data (`ex.data<-byUnit[1:25,]`) and then use the `dput` function, R will output a script to allow us to just recreate your first 25 rows. Then we have a table that looks like yours. `dput(ex.data)` That can help folks test code before posting and recreate any errors you may be having.

Answer (score 0):

Both `tapply` and `by` (which is a tapply wrapper I believe) should do the job. I think there are a few other ways as well. You might just be able to `summarize()` in the tidyverse if you want a dataframe that has all the totals in it.

Regardless, if what you're after is tabling some sum of quantities (`ACT_COUNT`) within a matrix where the column names are you `ACT_HR` and the row-names are the `UNIT`. This is what it looks like in using `tapply`

`tapply(byUnitHour$ACT_COUNT, byUnitHour[,1:2], sum)`

Enjoy!